# How can I make a responsive scale grid when dragging and droping Images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to JS and CSS so i'm looking for help to make a Grid container in which I drag into an icons in different sizes and I want them to arrange themselves based on the size of each icon and the amount of them.

Let's say the minimum size that each icon can scale down is 20% of its original size.

I tried a lot of methods without finding the perfect way..
If anyone can send me a complete example of something like that I would be thankfull!

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. You're also expected to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and showcase a **specific** problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic solution here. You're asking few questions - each has to be addressed separately and depends on the js framework you use. I'm going to assume you're using vanilla js / jQuery.

1. **Grid layout** - [`Bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/)  is a trendy and working-out-of-the-box framework. [Here's a simple grid example](http://interactjs.io/).
2. **Drag n drop** - There's no shortage in drag & drop libs like [`interactjs`](http://interactjs.io/), [`jQueryUI`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/), and [`Draggabilly`](https://draggabilly.desandro.com/) ([example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yyRapr))

**Don't attempt to achieve all your goals at once. Instead, implement the grid, understand it, then move to drag n drop and sort by size logic.**